# how to get the reference of a future object

Tags: java, reference

```
public void addteacher(Teacher teacher)
 {
    if (teacherSize < teacherList.length){
        teacherList[teacherSize] = teacher;
        teacherSize++;
        teacher.setTeacherDepartment(??????) // waht do i inset here ??
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("didnt add teacher");
    }
  }
```

The above method inserts a teacher object in an **`teacher[] teacherList`**.
**`teacherList`** belongs to a department  class
teacher is an instance of  teacher class

**`teacher.setTeacherDepartment()`** is to store in a teacher`s field the reference to that Department instance to witch it belongs as soon as it is inserted in it.
I don't know how to get the reference form the department instance inset in the parameter of the method.
note: i have not initiated the department instance yet!

Comment: first of all why you just dont use ArrayList instead of normal array. its easier to maintain.

Comment: its for a class in college and we cant use arraylist or any other colections. thanks for the sugestion =)

Comment: Please include definitions of classes, methods and variables, expected output and current output, this way it'll make helping you much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `addteacher` method belongs to `department` class. So, you can add department in this way .

```
teacher.setTeacherDepartment(this);
```